# Configuring Vue framework with webpack - styles are not applied

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack, sass

I have a problem with configuring the Vue framework with webpack. To be more precise, the problem is with styles included in the `<style>` tag in single file components. These styles are not applied even though my configuration looks exactly the same as in many tutorials regarding this configuration process. There are no errors during webpack build. Below I include some code snippets in which hopefully someone can find error or something is just missing.

**Webpack config file:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                exclude: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/assets/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    }
}
```

**Main entry file for webpack:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import TestComponent from '@components/TestComponent';

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(TestComponent)
});
```

**TestComponent file:**

```
<template>
    <h class="header">from {{ name }}</h>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TestComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            name: 'TestComponent'
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.header {
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
</style>
```

**index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Final result in a browser:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is from the `css-loader` enables `esModule` by default which causes the issue. I think it should work as you turn it off:

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    esModule: false // it's supposed to be turned off
  },
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Does Vue expect CommonJS syntax or the problems nature is something different? It is strange that in every tutorials even in Vue official tutorials such information is not included.

Comment: I think the release of v4 of  `css-loader` enables this option by default which makes no one aware of this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases/tag/v4.0.0